# Mysql non-sequential insert problem

Tags: php, mysql, insert, null

I have a table with 100,000 records described as:

```
ID primary unique int (5)
Ticket unique int (5)
user varchar (20)
```

Only fields populated on that table are the first two, ID and Ticket. I need to now assign a user to that ticket when requested. How can i do this? How can I find where the next null user is on the table?

Edit: Explaining Scenario as requested

Its a lottery system of sorts. The Ticket numbers have already been made and populated into the table. Now when a user signs up for a ticket, their username has to be inserted next to the next available ticket, in the user field. Im sure theres a much simpler way to do this by inserting the ticket with all the information on a new table, but this is th exact requirement as dumb as it sounds.

So how can I find out where the next null user is on the table?

Comment: You already have ID column, insert user by ID column.

Comment: @Stewie, how? INSERT INTO TABLE table (user) VALUES ('user') WHERE id = ???

Comment: Can you explain your scenario? Which table holds this information? What is the role of this table? How do you want to use this ID and Ticket?

Comment: @Aswhine Dhekane/ Edited the post with the scenario

Answer (score 0):

What is the sorting scheme of the table ?

If the Id numbers are sequential this should work:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE user is null ORDER by ID LIMIT 1
```

If Id numbers are NON sequential and you are OK with using the natural sort of the table (sorted as they were entered)

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE user is null LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the next NULL row by doing:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM Ticket
WHERE user IS NULL 
LIMIT 1;
```

When you update though you'll have to be careful you don't have a race condition with another process also getting the same ID.  You could prevent this duplicate allocation problem by having a separate table holding the `TicketAllocation`, and giving it a unique foreign key constraint pointing back to the `Ticket` table.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes `ID` is auto-incremented.

Start by finding the first record where the user field is null:

```
Select * from users where user is null order by id asc limit 1;
```

Then fill it in:

```
Update users set user = [username] where id = [id from select];
```

Comment: Note that ID is **not** autoincremented see table layout in the question above.

Comment: @Johan - He does mentioned that, yes, though seems to like my answer. It seems to me, from the way he described his problem, that he wasn't thinking about selecting by ID and was just thinking about the Ticket field (which won't be sequential).

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it in a single query:

```
UPDATE users SET user = [username] where id = 
(select min(id) from users where user is null)
```